# Measure of elements appearing infinitely many times

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ be Borel sets in the interval $[0,1]$, and let $\mu$ be a countably additive measure. Let $\epsilon>0$. Suppose $\mu(A_n)>\epsilon$ for all $n=1,2,\ldots$. Is it necessarily true that $\mu(\cap_{t=1}^\infty \cup_{n\geq t }A_n)>0$?

I think it should be true, because the measure in the question is for all elements $x$ that appears in infinitely many $A_n$s. Since the interval $[0,1]$ is finite (has measure $1$), and each $A_n$ contains a significant number of elements (measure $>\epsilon$), some elements must occur infinitely often. How can I turn this into a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_t = \bigcup_{n \geqslant n} A_n$. Then $\varepsilon < \mu(B_t) \leqslant 1$, and $B_{t+1} \subset B_t$. Hence $\chi_{B_t} \in L^1$ for all $t$, and by the monotone convergence theorem,

$$\mu\left(\bigcap_{t=1}^\infty B_t\right) = \lim_{t\to \infty} \mu(B_t) \geqslant \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Daniel. What is $\chi_{B_t}$, and why is it in $L^1$? I'm not familiar with these terminologies.

Comment: $\chi_{B_t}$ is the characteristic function (or indicator function, if you're into probability theory) of the set $B_t$. It's in $L^1$ since the sets $B_t$ are measurable and have finite measure.